# Running WebdriverIO 'spec' tests as node file

Tags: webdriver-io

I'm new to webdriverio. I don't understand how it's supposed to be configured and used within a node application. 
How do you run 'spec' tests when webdriverio is being imported? Can it be done?

```js
// based on http://webdriver.io/guide.html
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    },
    specs: './test/spec/**' // why doesn't this work, when it would work when run from the wdio cli
};

webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://www.google.com')
    .title(function(err, res) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + res.value);
    })
    .end();
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the wdio cli to run your tests?

Comment: I do use wdio cli for developing tests, since it goes through runtime faster. But, my final objective is for grunt to run the test for builds, but I would like trying to avoid writing to process.env, and I was thinking instead of using the ```spec``` property to define which tests to run, but it seems to not like being run from different paths.

Comment: Well, from the Webdriverio docs it looks like specs should be an array of strings rather than a string. Maybe that's it?

Comment: I ended up working through a more elegant implementation than my original intention. The solution uses the packgage grunt-env, that could also be used by wdio cli after setting environmental variables. Thanks @jrader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to use WebdriverIO. The standalone mode allows you to integrate test automation using the WebdriverIO API within arbitrary NodeJS scripts (e.g. [this example](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/examples/standalone/webdriverio.with.mocha.js)). It is often used to embed WebdriverIO into a different library like [Chimp.js](https://chimp.readme.io/).

The other way is the WDIO test runner (cli runner) which is better suited for sufficient e2e testing. It requires a configuration file (wdio.conf.js or whatever name you want) and to pass this file name as argument to the wdio cli command (e.g. [these examples](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/examples/wdio)). This is the common way if you want to create an e2e test suite for your project.