# How do I use wdio.conf.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm trying to use `webdriverio` with the `jasmine` test framework. I can run my test by typing `jasmine` at the command line. However, when I do `wdio wdio.conf.js` it opens a bunch of extra browsers which don't do anything. I'm just wondering what the point of the wdio.conf.js file is when I can just run jasmine at the commandline. Ultimately it's the same thing, right? However, I can't get the wdio.conf.js file to work in the same manner so it's useless to me. Perhaps I'm not managing the browser clients correctly but I don't see any guidelines on how this is commonly done. I read the documentation but it's pretty vague beyond auto-generating the wdio.conf file so that 'everything just works'. Am I supposed to use grunt or gulp to run my tests or are those tools separate from the wdio.conf idea?

I'm Just trying to get my head around all these different tools. All I need to do is make multiple automated tests to test a website. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This may help, https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/examples/standalone/webdriverio.with.jasmine.spec.js

I asked a similar question, which was answered by the main contributor here, [Running WebdriverIO 'spec' tests as node file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311721/running-webdriverio-spec-tests-as-node-file)